# Editing comments created in Close Review

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review-queues, comments

I have an issue editing comments that I created in the Close Vote Review. It says:

> An error occurred during comment submission

What I do:

0. Read the question
1. Add a comment and forget something
2. Edit the comment to include the forgotten sentence
3. Save Edits

If I open the question in a new tab, I'm able to edit the comment.

Using Firefox 47.0 on Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Asking other people i the [Close Vote Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), they could not reproduce it. Anyway, since I have 2 screenshots for evidence, I post it here.

Screenshots:

[image: Close vote comment 1]

[image: Close vote comment 2]

Comment: You could try opening the network developer tool of your browser and compare what happens when you attempt to edit directly or in a new tab. You can include the data in your question, but make sure to remove session cookies, or someone could hijack your session.

Comment: @Oriol: ok, I'll try. I'm not a web specialist, though. And for today I have exceeded the review limit.

Comment: It is an "it did not work" error message on the Ajax request.  Tends to be a connection problem but could be anything.  Not exactly appropriate error reporting on a programmer's site, is it :)  Try again later.

Comment: Now that I have my daily votes, I repro'd the error. But I guess I did it differently than you, since I used a custom reason (which took me to the next question). I went back with the browser buttons, and was unable to edit it until I refreshed the page.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that.

Comment: I can repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 47.0

Comment: I can repro this in the Low Quality queue as well, FF 45, Linux.

Comment: I can repro in any queue that allows comments... Chrome 51.0.2704.106 m, Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: I can repro this in AmigaOS 3.9, NCSA Mosaic 2.1.

Comment: @Sneftel: awesome!

Comment: As already noted, this is a client-side connectivity error. I checked the logs, and there's only a single comment edit request with a /review/* referrer from the 5 users that reported the repro case that came through to our servers. (it's an edit on [this deleted comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348634/automapper-and-inheritance-how-to-map/35485222#comment63493623_35485222) which was successful /cc @ThomasWeller)

Comment: @m0sa: as far as I can tell, my PC was online all the time. I was close voting 40 items (the maximum) and didn't notice any connectivity issues. Is it possible that the server (firewall or whatever) blocked this?

Comment: @m0sa It's been reproduced by a fair few users, so I both agree and disagree. I agree that it's a client-side connectivity error, *but* I disagree that the SE Network isn't at fault.